# Invalid type for AWS DynamoDB put-item via CLI (unicode v. dict)

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-dynamodb, aws-cli

I would like to add an item to my DynamoDB table via command line, but I've run into a type error.

The data that I'm trying to add is very simple:

```
{
  "id": "1"
}
```

The command I'm running is equally simple:

```
aws dynamodb put-item --table-name my_table --item '{ "id": "1" }'
```

The error I'm getting is:

```
Invalid type for parameter Item.id, value: 1, type: <type 'unicode'>, valid types: <type 'dict'>
```

I come from a JavaScript background, so I'm not familiar with `dict` types. From what I understand from some of the sources I've read, this is a Python thing? How do I change my data into something that DynamoDB can handle?

Answer (score 67, accepted):

you need to add the type information (I assume String here)

```
aws dynamodb put-item --table-name my_table --item '{ "id": {"S": "1" } }'
```

Comment: Ahh, I see what you mean. That's an interesting decision on their part. I guess the next step is to write a script to automate type discovery and reformatting. Thanks! http://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/reference/dynamodb/put-item.html#options

Comment: This is great answer..not sure if its documented anywhere but after adding the type information, it works :)

Answer (score 3):

We cannot provide a plain JSON schema as an input to the `dynamodb put-item` command. We need to provide the [attribute(s) data type along with its value](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/reference/dynamodb/put-item.html).

But if you have a complex JSON schema and you are new to the `aws dynamodb cli` commands then it becomes really tedious for you to prepare your input JSON file.

But we have an easy solution as well, please follow these steps:

- Prepare a sample JSON schema which you want to insert into your dynamodb table.
- Login to AWS Console, go to DynamoDB -> Tables -> , and from the top tabs chose `Items`, it will show you the data if any already.
- Now click on the `Create Item`, it will open a new window and from there choose the option `Text` instead of `Tree`. Paste your sample JSON schema there and save this item.
- Now Select that record and from `Actions` choose the option `Export to .csv`. This csv file contains your JSON attribute name (keys), their corresponding values along with their data type.
- Now most of the work has been done for you and you can easily construct the input JSON file for your `dynamodb put-item` command.