# python dynamodb - Invalid type for parameter

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, amazon-dynamodb, boto3

I am creating a dynamodb table via CDK.

```
    const table = new dynamodb.Table(this, "my-table", {
      tableName: StackConfiguration.tableName,
      partitionKey: { name: "file_id", type: dynamodb.AttributeType.STRING },
    });

    dynamoReplayTable.addGlobalSecondaryIndex({
      indexName: "processed",
      # ideally would like boolean here but doesn't seem to be an option
      partitionKey: { name: "processed", type: dynamodb.AttributeType.STRING },
    });
```

Then using boto 3 i am inserting data into the table like so

```
    failedRecord = {
        "file_id": str(file_id),
        "processed": "false",
        "payload": str(payload),
        "headers": str(headers),
    }

    table.put_item(Item=failedRecord)
```

I then have another service that reads the items, processes then and i want to update the processed field which is a global secondary index to true.

I have this code at the minute

```
    table.update_item(
        Key={"file_id": file_id}, AttributeUpdates={"processed": "true"},
    )
```

But this results in the following error

```
Parameter validation failed:
Invalid type for parameter AttributeUpdates.processed, value: true, type: <class 'str'>, valid types: <class 'dict'>
```

Comment: Is this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40953834/invalid-type-for-aws-dynamodb-put-item-via-cli-unicode-v-dict) helpful?

Comment: I had a look but that's for put item and I think because I don't specify a type when sending the data in it should default to string

Comment: Have you tried using ` AttributeUpdates={"processed": {"S": "true"}}`?

Comment: Yea when I try that i get [ERROR] ParamValidationError: Parameter validation failed:
Unknown parameter in AttributeUpdates.processed: "S", must be one of: Value, Action

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Resolved this with the following code

```
    table.update_item(
        Key={"file_id": file_id},
        UpdateExpression="SET processed_status = :processed",
        ExpressionAttributeValues={":processed": "true"},
    )
```

Comment: What if you have multiple values you want to update?

Comment: Then you would say         UpdateExpression="SET processed_status = :processed, second_thing_to_update = :whatever",

Answer (score 5):

DynamoDB handles dat types in a very specific way about which you can find more info [here](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazondynamodb/latest/developerguide/DynamoDBMapper.DataTypes.html) and [here](https://boto3.amazonaws.com/v1/documentation/api/latest/_modules/boto3/dynamodb/types.html).

In your case, the issue it's around the value `"true"` of your update command. Working with types can be tricky, `boto3` provides both a `TypeSerializer` and `TypeDeserializer` which you can use to handle the conversion for you:

```py
import boto3
from boto3.dynamodb.types import TypeSerializer

serializer = TypeSerializer()

my_single_value = "processed"

print(serializer.serialize(my_single_value))
# {'S': 'processed'}

my_dict_object = {
  "processed": "true"
}

print({k: serializer.serialize(v) for k, v in my_dict_object.items()})
# {'processed': {'S': 'true'}}
```